# The Bomb doesn't get placed when I want it to

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-8

I have a game that I made for Windows phone using XNA/C#, and now I've decided to go and add a Bomb to help the player.

Now I have setup a timer and a bool, so that only 1 bomb can be used per level.

But, as soon as the game opens, the bomb is already there! I don't think the timer is working.

```
bool canDrawBomb = false;


public static Texture2D bomb;
GameTimer bombTimer = new GameTimer();

protected override void Initialize()
{

    // Bomb timer.
    bombTimer.UpdateInterval.Add(new TimeSpan(50000));
    bombTimer.Update += bombTimer_Update;
    bombTimer.Start();

    base.Initialize();
}

void bombTimer_Update(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
{
    canDrawBomb = true;
    bombTimer.Stop();
}

protected override void LoadContent()
{

    bomb = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Bomb");
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{

        if (canDrawBomb)
        {
            // Draw the bomb.
            // TESTED: OK. The bomb can draw but not at right time.
            spriteBatch.Draw(bomb, new Vector2(), Color.White);
        }
}
```

Now the problem is that even though I have set the bombTimer to ah 50 seconds, it still draws at the very beginning of the game!

How can I fix this? I haev been at this for hours and it's driving me insane. I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: this has NSA written all over it

Comment: The title and your description imply two different things.

Comment: You initialize the bomb in your class initializer, which is executed when your object is created. Use another method, which is called at the approbiate time.

Comment: I was tought that in C# Boolean is always initially set to false; false is its default property.

Comment: @Jonesy are you referring to National Security Agency? Or is that just some joke about my noobiness?

Comment: Google Snowden, that will clue you into @Jonesy 's comment ;)

Comment: Yeah I was just poking fun about current issues in the U.S.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you set the timer to some stupidly high value?

Comment: @bæltazor: You are right, I just wanted to make sure it wasn't being set to true somewhere. I also had the code scrolled down and didn't see that it was explicitly set to false at the top.

Comment: I already thought 50 seconds was stupidly high considering I actually want it to be 5 seconds (that's another story), but I will see what happens now, @LokiSinclair

Comment: @LokiSinclair I set the timer to 5000000 and it's still showing at the start of the game.

Comment: Just a hint, probably not the solution: move `base.Initialize();` to the start of the method.

Answer (score 3):

The following line will *not* change the interval property (because the `TimeSpan.Add()` method makes a fresh copy, it does not change the existing TimeSpan):

```
  bombTimer.UpdateInterval.Add(new TimeSpan(50000));
```

just use

```
  bombTimer.UpdateInterval = new TimeSpan(50000);
```

Comment: Sigh. I still have a lot to learn. We need nanobot technology; I'm getting impatient. Thanks @HenkH :) _Edit_: It's still doing the same thing :-/

Comment: For reference on the UpdateInterval property:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametimer.updateinterval.aspx

Comment: @bæltazor - are you sure? Set a breakpoint in the Update handler and try to find out why/when it's called.

Comment: @bæltazor That should work. But you could always try `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` though you might need to add the `System.Windows` reference to the project

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the GameTimer.Update event is fired as soon as GameTimer.Start() is called. Add a counter variable and only set `canDrawBomb` to false on the second call (and equaly only disable the timer on the second call)

Or use the DispatcherTimer if that is available in XNA, which definitely does not fire on the `Start` call.

Comment: Ok, I have added an `int` that increments whenever Update is fired and if the value of int is >= 3 then I set canDrawBomb to true. But it still draws the bomb at the start of the game.

Comment: I ended up not using a Timer, but I am going to keep at it because I will eventually _need_ a timer at some point. I ended up drawing a bomb when the enemies have pretty much surrounded the player and the player's score is a quarter or less than their previous highscore.